# jQuery - apply CSS to first paragraph

Tags: jquery

I'm a beginning student learning jQuery, and the question says:

> Add a jQuery event listener to style the first paragraph when the mouse cursor is over it as color brown, bold in style and underlined.

I'm trying this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").first().hover(
        function() {
            (this).css('color','brown');
            (this).css('font-weight','bold');
            (this).css('text-decoration','underline');
        },
        function() {
            (this).css('color','black');
            (this).css('font-weight','normal');
            (this).css('text-decoration','none');
        }
    );
});
```

But it's not working. All p tags are wrapped in different div tags, does that make a difference? By "first paragraph," I think it means the first paragraph on the page.

Comment: seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m8ZSa/1/

Comment: There is a type, you are missing `$` sign in `(this)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is missin `$` wrapper.

`(this).css` css is a method of jquery object. but there you are trying to invoke it on DOM element by saying `(this).css`.

A shorthand for `.first()` is `:first`. You can also refer to it as `$("p:first").hover(`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/APSzn/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("p").first().hover(

        function() {
            var elem = $(this);
            elem .css('color','brown');
            elem .css('font-weight','bold');
            elem .css('text-decoration','underline');
        },
        function() {
           var elem = $(this);
            elem .css('color','black');
            elem.css('font-weight','normal');
            elem.css('text-decoration','none');
        }
    );
});
```

Just to extend and demonstrate your question on how to select first paragraph of only that particular div. You can use selector chaining/filtering to ensure only intended paragraphs are affected. See the [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Zds6a/) and the code below where the style is targeted only to the para of div with class A.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("div.A p:first").hover(

    function() {
            var elem = $(this);
            elem .css('color','brown');
            elem .css('font-weight','bold');
            elem .css('text-decoration','underline');
        },
        function() {
           var elem = $(this);
            elem .css('color','black');
            elem.css('font-weight','normal');
            elem.css('text-decoration','none');
        }
});
```

Comment: Still not working. It might have something to do with the fact that it's wrapped in a div tag with a class, but there's another div group with the same class that also has paragraphs, so I don't know how to select just that paragraph.

Comment: Wow, it worked on the jsfiddle site, but not my browser for some reason. It's a PHP file, but it's already on the server and everything, so that shouldn't be the issue... odd. I'll try another browser I suppose. Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: Also, I just realized it was because I never linked the jQuery library to my PHP file BEFORE I linked my own JavaScript file, they were in the wrong order. That was the only issue after your guys' pointing out my typos.

Comment: p.s. instead of using `$(this)` so much in the code use `var $this = $(this);` and then reference is as `$this` or since what you have can be simplified then combine everything like this `$(this).css({ 'color' : 'brown', 'font-weight' : 'bold' , 'text-decoration' : 'underline'});`

Answer (score 1):

Try warping all (this) as $(this)

i.e:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").first().hover(
        function() {
            $(this).css('color','brown');
            $(this).css('font-weight','bold');
            $(this).css('text-decoration','underline');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).css('color','black');
            $(this).css('font-weight','normal');
            $(this).css('text-decoration','none');
        }
    );
});
```

Although I don't think this is the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try also `$('body p:first').hover(function() { .... })`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p').first().hover(
        function() {
            $(this).css({'color':'brown', 'font-weight':'bold','text-decoration':'underline'} );

        },
        function() {
            $(this).css({'color':'black', 'font-weight':'normal','text-decoration':'none'} );

        }
    );
});
```

Comment: It's not doing anything when I hover the mouse over the first paragraph. This paragraph is wrapped in a div with a class "special", but there's another div with the same class that also has paragraphs, so I'm not sure what to do if it says "first paragraph."